# MVC 5.2.3.0 Project built in MonoDevelop 404 Server Error in '/directory' Application. The resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mono, asp.net-mvc-5

I built a MVC 5.2.3.0 application:

### The Local Dev environment consist of

My OS is Linux Mint 17.1 - 64 bit
My IDE is Mono develop 5.7
My development / Debug environment is the the built in xsp4 server that you can install with mono.

### My Test Web Server

Windows Vista SP2 32 Bit
IIS 7
.NET Framework version: 4.0.30319.34209 (32-bit)

### My problem

When I debug in MonoDevelop the application runs fine
But when I bin deploy it to my web server I get a error 
 *HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.*

I been through  the file structure over and over and I don't understand what I am missing.

Does any one here have idea.
Thank you in advance

**Here is the MVC diagnostics report.**

---

Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Diagnostics Information

Operating system: Microsoft Windows NT 6.0.6002 Service Pack 2
.NET Framework version: 4.0.30319.34209 (32-bit)
Web server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Integrated pipeline: True
Worker process: w3wp.exe
AppDomain: Homogenous = True, FullTrust = True

Worker process: w3wp.exe
ASP.NET MVC Assembly Information (System.Web.Mvc.dll)

Assembly version: ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3 RTM (5.2.30128.0)
Full name: System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
Code base: file:///M:/bsandy/bin/System.Web.Mvc.DLL
Deployment: bin-deployed

ASP.NET MVC Futures Assembly Information (Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll)
/.
All Loaded Assemblies

65 assemblies are loaded.

```
Antlr3.Runtime, Version=3.5.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb42632606e9261f
App_global.asax.cndxl5jx, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
App_Web_bhwlrj4f, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
BSW, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.JScript, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
SMDiagnostics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Configuration.Install, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Drawing.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Net.Http.Extensions, Version=2.2.28.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=4.2.28.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Runtime.Caching, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ServiceModel.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.DynamicData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Mobile, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.RegularExpressions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.WorkflowServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
WebGrease, Version=1.6.5135.21930, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
WebMatrix.Data, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
WebMatrix.WebData, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
```

Diagnostics version: Tuesday, July 10, 2012 (v12)
Report generated on: Wednesday, February 25, 2015 7:26:16 PM

Comment: I don't see that assembly (System.Web.Mvc) in your list of loaded assemblies? How are you including it in the project?

Comment: I copied it over into the bin folder. if you look towards the bottom it is loaded.  System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Comment: Is Mono installed on the web server?

Comment: No, The web server is IIS7 on Windows Server . I don't plan on deploying Mono to it. There reason is, ultimately this application will be published on the internet.   And the Hosting service is using IIS 7 on a Windows environment. I wonder though could it be that IIS7 does not support MVC 5 and higher? Maybe I should use MVC 4?

Comment: Ah OK I see so you're developing on Linux and deploying to Windows. Do you need to register asp.net with IIS again? `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir`

Comment: I registered IIS again as  you suggested, but unfortunately NO change, a NOTE however, the web server is 32bit  so just the **Framework** directory was there. Let me add this information, the computer that I built the MVC app on is a 64bit  ,

Comment: After I re-registered IIS  I re-ran a newer version of the Diagnostics and updated the information above for viewing. On another **NOTE** just to see if it works I create a MVC application with **Visual Studio 2010 Express** it loads fine on the Web server, that should rule out any server issues right? , it seems that anything I created with MonoDevelop  on my Linux Computer gets the original error posted in the question above.

Comment: Even if the web server is Windows Server, you still need Mono installed don't you? Also what platform are you targeting Any CPU, x86, x64?

Comment: I have built many ASP.NET Web form applications using MonoDevelop,and they all run just fine on IIS, with no need for the Mono framework. This is my first MVC,net application and from what I have read  as long as you have the correct files/folders on your server  that your application uses it should work. So, I don't see why you would need Mono installed. I could be wrong about it though.  I don't believe my web host uses Mono on their server as well, I just can't see the Mono framework being a requirement for a MVC application written in MonoDevelop.   My target is any CPU

Comment: In this particular case I think I have all the needed files and folders but again I may be missing something.  The version of MonoDevelop  5.7 I am using does not have a *Publish* feature so you are sort of left to a manual publish *copy and paste /ftp * process to the server. This may be the problem as well, because I may not be doing something to properly publish the site, make sense?

Comment: Do you have any other ASP.NET or MVC applications running on that server? What app pool are you running under? Is MVC installed on the web server?

Comment: Sorry for my delay I was doing some testing. Yes MVC is installed. and Just to make sure I built a simple ASP.NET WebForms application with MonoDevelop, then  manually copied the files over and the application loaded. But no matter what I do I when it comes to MVC the application still gets the above error.

Comment: NOW I DID TEST THIS --- I downloaded  VisualStudio Express created a simple MVC application with it, then published it and it worked. I don't intend t use VisualStudio but I just wanted to make sure MVC worked, and it does. So the problem I think is MONO Develop is not doing something that I am missing in my file structure. makesense

Comment: Have you tried installing Mono on that server? I'm still not 100% sure you can host a Mono application without Mono installed - even on Windows.

Comment: Timothy -- Thanks for the help, I installed mono but change.  I think what I am going to do is just write the application in WebForms because I know that works, and seems like MVC  is so sensitive although I read a lot of good things about it. Even still I been working on this for a month and have not made any lead way so, i am just going to move forward with what I know is working.  I think if my environment was all one in the same I think things would work better.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you should not, in anyway, need Mono installed on the web server.  I won't go into the specifics of why, but I'm sure you can research that.

The issue you are likely facing is one of Assembly bindings.  If you could post your web.config, specifically the assembly bindings section that may help.  However, I would look and make sure that they are all pointing to the correct versions.

Also, you could try enabling the fusionlog to give you a better idea of what library it thinks is missing.